# There is a better expression for $\nabla g(x)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f\in C^1(X,\Bbb R^n)$ with $X\subset \Bbb R^m$ a differentiable function and $$g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R,\quad x\mapsto \cos(|f(x)|^2)$$ Show that $g$ is continuously differentiable and find $\nabla g$.

*We assumes here that $\Bbb R^k$ are inner products with the euclidean inner product.*

What I did was: by the chain rule, provided that the sine function is continuously differentiable and also $f$, the question reduces to show that $h(y):=|y|^2$ is continuously differentiable for each $y\in\Bbb R^n$, what is immediate from the continuity of it partial derivatives.

Thus is easy to check that

$$\partial g(x)=\partial [(\sin |f(x)|^2)]=\cos(|f(x)|^2)\cdot\partial[(f(x)|f(x))]=\cos(|f(x)|^2)2(f(x)|\partial f(x))$$

And we knows that

$$\nabla g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^m\partial_k g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^m\partial g(x)e_k$$

where $e_1,\ldots,e_m$ is the standard orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^m$. But Im unable to find a better (more explicit) expression for $\nabla g$, there is some one? Some help will be appreciated, thank you.